# Set vim colorscheme in modeline

Tags: vim, configuration

I'm trying to set my colorscheme in the modeline.  I tried it a few ways, but none of them works.  I get an "Unknown option: colorscheme" error.

```
# vim: colorscheme dark_foo:set ft=foo:
```

How can it be set in the modeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The modeline consists of option settings. There is no "colorscheme" option. colorscheme is just a command that essentially executes "runtime colors/foo".

You can get an approximation of what you're asking for by creating an autocmd that sets your colorscheme and is triggered by some option that is actually settable in your modeline.

Answer (score 4):

detailing answer of Laurence, example: force js highlighting:

first line of file you want to get the intended highlighting: `# vim: ft=javascript`

If you want you can then deviate from the default colorscheme via .vimrc:

`autocmd FileType javascript colorscheme badwolf`